# send authenticated request via supertest with mocha on a passport managed API

Tags: node.js, authentication, mocha.js, passport.js, supertest

It's been 24 hours since I first had this issue. I know there plenty of similar ones, specially on SO but I can't figure out how to solve it.

I have specific requirement :

- I have some routes to test without authentication.
- I have some routes to test with specific users.
- I use a passport local strategy.

So I decided to test my API like :

```
var request = require('supertest');

...

describe('Routes', function () {

  var anAgent;
  var anotherAgent;

  before(function (done) {
    anAgent = request.agent(app);
    anotherAgent = request.agent(app);

    async.parallel([
      function (callback) {
        anAgent
          .post('/api/users/login')
          .send({user:user, password:password})
          .expect(200)
          .end(callback);
      },
      function (callback) {
        userAgent
          .post('/api/users/login')
          .send({user:anotherUser, password:anotherPassword})
          .expect(200)
          .end(callback);
      }
    ], done);
  });

  describe('/superroute', function () {

      it('should return the user', function (done) {
        anAgent
          .post('/api/superroute')
          .send(params)
          .expect(200)
          .end(function (err, res) {
            should.not.exist(err);
            res.body.err.should.equal('Super route');
            done();
          });
      });

      ...
 });

 ...

});
```

The route `/superroute` is describe like

```
express.Router().post('/superroute', auth.ensureAuthenticated, superCtrl.superroute);
```

Where `ensureAuthenticated` middleware call the `req.isAuthenticated()` of passport.

This API works fine when I use it from a simple angular front but when I run the test with mocha, the `passport.deserializeUser` method is not called and `isAuthenticated` return `false`. With the fact that the user is correctly logged and retrieved from the `/login` call, it's all I know.

So the call returns 401 instead of 200.

What can I've possibly missed ?